# libvirt-php receives the error: internal error Unable to locate libvirtd daemon in /usr/sbin

Tags: php, centos, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I have installed php-libvirt as well as all required packages
I have setup my php file as follows:

```
<?php
echo “WebAdmin 0.1Beta”;
echo “<br/>”;

$uri=”qemu:///system”;
echo (“Connecting to libvirt (URI:$uri)\n”.”<br/>”.”<br/>”);
$conn=libvirt_connect($uri,false);
if ($conn==false)
{
echo (“Libvirt last error: “.libvirt_get_last_error().”\n”);
exit;
}
```

However when I load the page I get:

```
WebAdmin 0.1Beta
Connecting to libvirt (URI:qemu:///system)

Libvirt last error: internal error Unable to locate libvirtd daemon in /usr/sbin (to override, set $LIBVIRTD_PATH to the name of the libvirtd binary)
```

It works fine from the command line when I run

```
[root@localhost ~]# virsh -c qemu:///system list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
```

I checked Libvirtd status, it's also running

```
[root@localhost ~]# service libvirtd status
libvirtd (pid  14017) is running...
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Current libvirt doesn't have any code which would report that particular error message, so what version of libvirt are you using there ? (eg virsh version).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `libvirtd` executable in `/usr/sbin`?

You should find where it is and point `$LIBVIRTD_PATH` to the correct folder.

If you run the script as non-root user then the executable could be there, just the script does not have permissions to use it.

p.s. probably this question is for Server Fault

Comment: noo i execute the script as a root as well as the whole install process,

Comment: and i don't know how to edit the variable $LIBVIRTD_PATH

Comment: i cant find the libvirtd executable in  /usr/sbin, it's under /etc/init.d

Comment: Can you try to run `find / -name 'libvirtd'` and paste the results in the question? Changing LIBVIRTD_PATH can be done by running `export LIBVIRTD_PATH=/path/to/folder` prior to running the script, or putting that line in `~/.profile`

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# find / -name 'libvirtd'
/var/lock/subsys/libvirtd
/etc/logrotate.d/libvirtd
/etc/sysconfig/libvirtd
/etc/sysctl.d/libvirtd
/etc/rc.d/init.d/libvirtd
/usr/sbin/libvirtd

Comment: I'm out of ideas then if you're running as root. Obviously it is under `/usr/sbin` which is the default location. If you're using apparmor check out its rules.